# Can other version of Microsoft Visual Studio be opened with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Can other version of Microsoft Visual Studio be opened with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 C#?

Answer (score 2):

Projects created with previous versions can, and will invoke a project conversion wizard. Projects created with later versions cannot, generally. I found a [downgrade utility](http://mises.org/Community/blogs/misestech/archive/2008/02/28/visual-studio-2008-to-2005-downgrade-utility.aspx) on, of all places, Mises.org. I didn't write it, and haven't even tried it, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You can open projects created with older releases of Visual Studio 2005, like 2002. A migration assistent will help you to update the project files.

Comment: hi Matten i have a file i think is version 2008 or 2010..but i would need it to be opened in 2005..so i need the help of migration assistant? do u mind telling me wat is it?

Comment: Please refer to the answer of Chris and have a look at the downgrade utility he proposed. Without any project conversion you're not able to open projects from VS2008 or VS2010 in VS2005.

Comment: A migration or conversion assistent helps you to update the solution and csproj files to be readable. Newer versions of Visual Studio are using solution files with features VS2005 does not understand, but the sln file knows which version it belongs to and so VS2005 refuses to open it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can run, say, an instance of Visual Studio 2008 next to 2005, then yes. I've done it many times. When you double-click on a .sln file, what actually runs is a little stub program that examines the .sln and decides which is the best version of Visual Studio to launch it in.

If you're asking whether you can open a solution created in VS 2005 in another version of VS, then the only restriction is that it has to be more recent than VS 2005. EG: you can't open a Visual Studio 2008 solution in VS 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can change the version of the solution file manualy. Open it in text editor and manually change the line "`Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00`" to earlier. Sometimes can help :).